# How to redirect a HTTP site to HTTPS site using 301 redirect instead of 302

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I have a woocommerce website that is using https. The https if being redirected using a 302 redirect and I need to change this to a 301 redirect. I have the "Force SSL (HTTPS) on the checkout pages (an SSL Certificate is required)." option checked in the woo commerce settings and my htaccess file is below

What's the best way to change from a 302 to 301 redirect?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Forcing HTTPS
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.aransweatersdirect.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: The first hit when googling for "apache 301 redirect" is [this](http://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/301-redirects/) and it looks like it describes what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to keep `http->https` redirect rule before default WP rule which rewrites every URI to `index.php`.

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**Then make sure to keep `https` in your home and site URL of wordress permalink settings.**

Comment: Can you explain abit what those lines that question author didn't have, do? It also did work for me but I would like to understand why it worked and what was causing this.

Comment: I have added it in question